# facebook like box shown only if the site was not liked yet by the user

Tags: facebook, popup, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I'm new in Facebook developer things and i have to make a Facebook like on my website.So I have a website and i made a Facebook page for it. What i want is to somehow detach if the user is already liked my page, because if so i want to show the like box in a popup window, but i could not find a still working description for it on the internet. I have tried to make it work by using the Facebook API but it was not working either and i also tried to use Facebook php but that was not working. 
Am i able to do it on my site? If yes, how?